# G++ is throwing an error on some basic inline asm

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm trying to execute
`asm("pushad");` yet it's throwing an error saying "invalid instruction mnemonic "pushad" and then shows the line. I couldn't find anything on google and it SHOULD work. I've also tried __pushad, _pushad and PUSHAD.

Comment: What is the target architecutre? Are you sure it supports the instruction `pushad`?

Comment: I'm running in VMWare, but its ia32 lol

Comment: works fine on my windows host using msvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G++ uses the 16bit version, `pusha`

Comment: This was an answer. I should use pusha instead of pushad. I couldn't mark as answer for two days.